# Laravel SQL select query where DateTimestamp contains this month and year

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, datetime

I'm trying to make a SQL query where I can check if the DateTimestamp contains this month and year.

A part of the query:

```
$leads = DB::table('leads') 
        ->leftJoin('invoices', function($join2) {
            $join2->on('leads.id', '=', 'invoices.lead_id');
        })
   ->where('invoices.chance', '!=', 0)
        ->where('invoices.updated_at', '=', date('m-Y')) //Check if DateTimestamp(updated_at) contains Year and month
            ->select('leads.*')
```

I tried it with date_parse, new DateTime(), but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `whereMonth()` and `whereYear()` to achieve this:

```
$leads = DB::table('leads') 
    ->leftJoin('invoices', function($join2) {
        $join2->on('leads.id', '=', 'invoices.lead_id');
    })
    ->where('invoices.chance', '!=', 0)
    ->whereMonth('invoices.updated_at', '=', date('m')) // changed
    ->whereYear('invoices.updated_at', '=', date('Y')) // changed
    ->select('leads.*');
```